# Why does this simple threaded C++ program crash upon exit unless I call thread.join()?

Tags: c++, multithreading

The program below will end up failing with a message regarding `abort()` being called.

I'm starting a thread that simple prints to `cout`. If I use `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`, I get the error. If I remove this, I get the error. If I call `join()` on the thread, everything works fine.

Shouldn't the thread have terminated long before the 1000 ms delay was up? Why is this causing an error? I can't believe calling `join()` is a requirement for a thread.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class ThreadTest
{
public:
    ThreadTest() : _t{ &ThreadTest::Run, this } {}
    void Wait() { _t.join(); }

private:

    void Run(){
        std::cout << "In thread" << std::endl;
    }

    std::thread _t;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ThreadTest tt;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    // tt.Wait();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you compile this program? What platform? What OS? What compiler? What version? What flags? What optimisation level?

Comment: FYI, this behavior is mandated by the standard and should occur for "any of the above".  I reproduced in Windows, MSVC 2013, Debug/Win32.

Comment: Believe it or not: calling either `join` or `detach` is a requirement for correct behavior of `std::thread`. I recommend `join` (because you still need synchronization in the `detach` case).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) on thread class destructor :

> **`~thread()`**: Destroys the thread object. If **`*this`** still has an associated running thread (i.e. **`joinable() == true`**), **`std::terminate()`** is called.

And [`joinable()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable) :

> [...] A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore joinable.

So you have to call `join()` explicitely before your thread variable is automatically destroyed or use the [`detach()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) member function.

Comment: Off the top of my head, this differs from `Boost.Thread`'s behaviour in this scenario. Am I right?

Comment: Apparently, [up to boost 1.56.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.destructor) it was different. Quote from the link : `[...] Thus the programmer must ensure that the destructor is never executed while the thread is still joinable.`

Comment: Ok - that's really important to remember then.

Comment: Always tough to decide which answer to accept when there are two nearly identical... I choose this one to give the guy with less rep a little bit more. :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Check [cppreference's `std::thread` page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

> A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore joinable.
>
> [`the destructor`] Destroys the thread object. If `*this` still has an associated running thread (i.e. `joinable() == true`), **`std::terminate()` is called**.

To get the behavior you want, you'd need to call `_t.detach()` before exiting from `main`:

> [`detach()`] Separates the thread of execution from the thread object, allowing execution to continue independently. Any allocated resources will be freed once the thread exits.
>   After calling `detach` `*this` no longer owns any thread.